# Laravel: Custom language files not being loaded for package

Tags: php, laravel, translation, service-provider

I am using the package mailcoach by spatie to host my own email marketing. However, I would like to edit the language files. Regarding to the Laravel [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/localization#overriding-package-language-files) this can be done by:

> So, for example, if you need to override the English translation
> strings in messages.php for a package named skyrim/hearthfire, you
> should place a language file at:
> resources/lang/vendor/hearthfire/en/messages.php

So, in my case the package is called `spatie/laravel-mailcoach` which would resolve in `resources/lang/vendor/laravel-mailcoach/de/messages.php`. However, there are two problems I face.

1. When I publish the language files from the package the folder is called `mailcoach` instead of `laravel-mailcoach`. However, I have tried both (at the same time) and neither of my language files were loaded. How can this be?
2. I want to load a `.json` file instead of a `.php` file. I **assume** that it will work as described above. Which would mean the correct path file would be `resources/lang/vendor/laravel-mailcoach/de.json`. Is this correct?

If `2` is correct, why is Laravel still loading the wrong language file?

I dug a little into the `Illuminate\Translation\Translator` file and added a `dd($this)` for the `get` method which will retrieve the correct translation for the given key. What I found is the following:

```
Illuminate\Translation\Translator {#604 ▼
  #loader: Illuminate\Translation\FileLoader {#603 ▼
    #files: Illuminate\Filesystem\Filesystem {#92}
    #path: "Programmieren/MyWebsiteProject/resources/lang"
    #jsonPaths: array:4 [▼
      0 => "Programmieren/MyWebsiteProject/vendor/arcanedev/log-viewer/translations"
      1 => "Programmieren/MyWebsiteProject/vendor/llaski/nova-scheduled-jobs/src/../resources/lang"
      2 => "Programmieren/MyWebsiteProject/resources/lang/vendor/nova-scheduled-jobs"
      3 => "Programmieren/MyWebsiteProject/vendor/spatie/laravel-mailcoach/src/../resources/lang/"
    ]
    #hints: array:3 [▼
      "log-viewer" => "Programmieren/MyWebsiteProject/vendor/arcanedev/log-viewer/translations"
      "NovaScheduledJobs" => "Programmieren/MyWebsiteProject/vendor/llaski/nova-scheduled-jobs/src/../resources/lang"
      "validationRules" => "Programmieren/MyWebsiteProject/vendor/spatie/laravel-validation-rules/src/../resources/lang/"
    ]
  }
  #locale: "de"
  #fallback: "en"
  #loaded: array:1 [▼
    "*" => array:1 [▼
      "*" => array:1 [▼
        "de" => array:403 [▼
        ...
        // my translations
        ...
        ]
      ]
    ]
  ]
  #selector: null
  #parsed: []
}
```

As you can see in the `jsonPaths` array, the `mailcoach` language files are not the one in my `resources/lang/vendor/laravel-mailcoach` or `resources/lang/vendor/mailcoach` folder but rather the original one.

Can anybody explain me why this happens and not the files under `resources/lang/vendor` are being loaded?

What is interesting is the fact that when I add the line `$this->loadJsonTranslationsFrom(resource_path() . '/lang/vendor/mailcoach');` to my `boot` function in my `AppServiceProvider` the `jsonPaths` array above gets one more item  `Programmieren/MyWebsiteProject/resources/lang/vendor/mailcoach` which is the correct one.

And then my customized language files are also being used but the original one are still being loaded. How can this be?

Besides that I would like to know why I even have to register my custom language file? This is not a normal behavior... I would like to find the bug/problem.

Kind regards

Comment: I would like to point out that as you can see above in the `jsonPaths` array that the custom language files for other packages gets loaded without separately registering them...

Answer (score 1):

I believe I found the solution (using Laravel 8.x):

In `vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Translation/FileLoader.php` see

```
protected function loadNamespaceOverrides(array $lines, $locale, $group, $namespace)
{
    $file = "{$this->path}/vendor/{$namespace}/{$locale}/{$group}.php";

    if ($this->files->exists($file)) {
        return array_replace_recursive($lines, $this->files->getRequire($file));
    }

    return $lines;
}
```

Based on that I assumed that not the package name (like `hearthfire` in `skyrim/hearthfire`) is the real deal, but the namespace of the package – in my case I used for `statamic/cms` `statamic` instead of `cms`, so placing a file in

```
resources/lang/vendor/statamic/de/messages.php
```

worked for me.